# MongoDB Query solution

Tags: express, mongoose

**What is the optimize Query for this situation**

So the Situation is a User is following many XY user and these XY have got events, So what will the best and optimize query to get all the events from his followers XY in sorted form (sort by Date). I have got create Date in my schema

**This is my User Schema**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    followers:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'XY'
    }]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**Here is My XY schema**

```
var XY= new Schema({

    events:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event'
    }],

});


var XY= mongoose.model('XY',XY);
module.exports = XY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
User.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(<userId here>) } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$followers" } },
            { $lookup: { from: 'XY', localField: 'followers', foreignField: '_id', as: 'followers' } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$followers" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$followers.events" } },
            { $lookup: { from: 'Event', localField: 'followers.events', foreignField: '_id', as: 'followers.events' } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$followers.events" } },
            { $sort: { "followers.events.createdDate": **-1** } }, // -1 -> desc, 1 -> asc
            {
                "$project":
                {
                    "_id": "$followers.events._id",
                    "createdDate": "$followers.events.createdDate",
                    // populate other event details here accordingly
                }
            }
           ], function (err, events, next) {
       });
```

*$lookup* lets you populate a sub-document from a different schema.
 After populating, the resultant documents will be an array, so *$unwind* is used before working on them.

note that *$unwind* is also used before doing a *$lookup* here as the field we are trying to populate is itself an array.